# What condition should I supply for a custom cross join in an Azure Data Factory dataflow?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In a dataflow, I have two datasets with one column each. Let's say dataset a with column a and dataset b with column b.

I want to cross join them, but when I select the custom cross join option it asks me to specify a condition. I don't understand what I need to supply here, I just want all the records from column a to be cross joined with all the records from column b. What should I put? I tried checking the official Microsoft documentation but there were no examples there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cross join in a `join` transformation of azure data factory dataflow requires a condition on which the join has to be applied. I have done the following to demonstrate how do cross join on the example that you have given.

- I have two datasets (one column each). Dataset A has one column `a` with the following values.

[image]

- Dataset B has column `b` with the following values.

[image]

- I have used join transformation to join both the sources. Now, the dataflow join transformation prompts you to specify a cross join condition. If you don't have any condition and just want to apply cross join on all the data from both datasets, you give the cross join condition value as **`true()`** (As you want to do in this case).

[image]

- This would apply cross join on all the records of `column a` with all the records of `column b`.

[image]

This is how you can achieve your requirement. If you have any condition, you can pass it to apply cross join based on it instead of using `true()`. Refer to this [official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-join#:%7E:text=that%20aren%27t%20matched.-,Custom%20cross%20join,-Cross%20join%20outputs) to understand more about joins.